# .htaccess multiple redirects with fallback

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to create some kind of redirection script using `.htaccess` to map short urls (`like example.com/1` to other urls). To do so, I've created this:

```
RedirectPermanent /1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
RedirectPermanent /2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

So far, that's working. However, it's missing a fallback. I'd like to add a 404 page that is shown whenever someone tries to navigate a URL that doesn't have any redirect (yet).

I've tried adding this:

```
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.html$
RewriteRule .* /404.html [L,R=302]
```

Obviously, this isn't working, because now ALL calls are redirected to `404.html`. I thought about adding the redirects as conditions, but since there might be many redirects that approach seems very bad to me.

What can I do instead?

Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this now, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Please comment if you have any advices.

```
RewriteRule ^/1$ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/2$ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.html$
RewriteRule .* /404.html [L,R=302]
```